# How to implement full text search on complex nested JSONB in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, jsonb, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-9.6

I have pretty complex JSONB stored in one `jsonb` column.

DB table looks like:

```
 CREATE TABLE sites (
   id text NOT NULL,
   doc jsonb,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
 )
```

Data we are storing in `doc` column is a complex nested `JSONB` data:

```
   {
      "_id": "123",
      "type": "Site",
      "identification": "Custom ID",
      "title": "SITE 1",
      "address": "UK, London, Mr Tom's street, 2",
      "buildings": [
          {
               "uuid": "12312",
               "identification": "Custom ID",
               "name": "BUILDING 1",
               "deposits": [
                   {
                      "uuid": "12312",
                      "identification": "Custom ID",             
                      "audits": [
                          {
                             "uuid": "12312",         
                              "sample_id": "SAMPLE ID"                
                          }
                       ]
                   }
               ]
          } 
       ]
    }
```

So structure of my `JSONB` looks like:

```
SITE 
  -> ARRAY OF BUILDINGS
     -> ARRAY OF DEPOSITS
       -> ARRAY OF AUDITS
```

We need to implement full text search by some values in each of type of entry:

```
SITE (identification, title, address)
BUILDING (identification, name)
DEPOSIT (identification)
AUDIT (sample_id)
```

SQL query should run a full text search in these field values only.

I guess need to use `GIN` indexes and something like `tsvector`, but do not have enough Postgresql background.

So, my question is it possible to index and then query such nested `JSONB` structures?

Comment: The first shot would be "denormalize" the  storage: sacrifice some storage place for brevity. Extract needed data in separate fields: site, building, deposit, audit,   containing pure string contantenation of needed fields, i.e.  `building.identification ||';'||building.title||';'||building.address` etc.  (this can be done using postgres' functions as default values, or trigger-based, if your data is modified). Then create GIN indexes on those fields -> and then construct your corresponding full text queries on those fields

Comment: Thanks @IlyaDyoshin . I like your idea - will try to experiment with it.

Comment: or you can wait till 10.0 release - where json/jsonb FTS will be first class citizen https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/release-10.html

Comment: wow thanks for info @IlyaDyoshin :beers:

Comment: Guys, see @Nick 's approach below. I tested it - it works brilliant + 1

Answer (score 18):

Let's add new column of `tsvector` type:

```
alter table sites add column tsvector tsvector;
```

Now let's create a trigger that will collect lexems, organize them and put to our tsvector. We will use 4 groups (A, B, C, D) -- this a special tsvector's feature that allows you to distinguish lexems later, at search time (see examples in manual https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html; unfortunately, this feature support only up to 4 groups becase developers reserved only 2 bits for that, but we are lucky here, we need only 4 groups):

```
create or replace function t_sites_tsvector() returns trigger as $$
declare
  dic regconfig;
  part_a text;
  part_b text;
  part_c text;
  part_d text;
begin
  dic := 'simple'; -- change if you need more advanced word processing (stemming, etc)

  part_a := coalesce(new.doc->>'identification', '') || ' ' || coalesce(new.doc->>'title', '') || ' ' || coalesce(new.doc->>'address', '');

  select into part_b string_agg(coalesce(a, ''), ' ') || ' ' || string_agg(coalesce(b, ''), ' ')
  from (
    select 
      jsonb_array_elements((new.doc->'buildings'))->>'identification',
      jsonb_array_elements((new.doc->'buildings'))->>'name'
  ) _(a, b);

  select into part_c string_agg(coalesce(c, ''), ' ')
  from (
    select jsonb_array_elements(b)->>'identification' from (
      select jsonb_array_elements((new.doc->'buildings'))->'deposits'
    ) _(b)
  ) __(c);

  select into part_d string_agg(coalesce(d, ''), ' ')
  from (
    select jsonb_array_elements(c)->>'sample_id'
    from (
      select jsonb_array_elements(b)->'audits' from (
        select jsonb_array_elements((new.doc->'buildings'))->'deposits'
      ) _(b)
    ) __(c)
  ) ___(d);

  new.tsvector := setweight(to_tsvector(dic, part_a), 'A')
    || setweight(to_tsvector(dic, part_b), 'B')
    || setweight(to_tsvector(dic, part_c), 'C')
    || setweight(to_tsvector(dic, part_d), 'D')
  ;
  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql immutable;

create trigger t_sites_tsvector
  before insert or update on sites for each row execute procedure t_sites_tsvector();
```

^^ -- scroll it, this snippet is bigger than it looks (especially of you have MacOS w/o scrollbars...)

Now let's create GIN index to speedup search queries (makes sense if you have many rows -- say, more than hundreds or thousands):

```
create index i_sites_fulltext on sites using gin(tsvector);
```

And now we insert something to check:

```
insert into sites select 1, '{
      "_id": "123",
      "type": "Site",
      "identification": "Custom ID",
      "title": "SITE 1",
      "address": "UK, London, Mr Tom''s street, 2",
      "buildings": [
          {
               "uuid": "12312",
               "identification": "Custom ID",
               "name": "BUILDING 1",
               "deposits": [
                   {
                      "uuid": "12312",
                      "identification": "Custom ID",
                      "audits": [
                          {
                             "uuid": "12312",
                              "sample_id": "SAMPLE ID"
                          }
                       ]
                   }
               ]
          }
       ]
    }'::jsonb;
```

Check with `select * from sites;` – you must see that `tsvector` column is filled with some data.

Now let's query it:

```
select * from sites where tsvector @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'sample');
```

-- it must return our record. In this case, we search for `'sample'` word and we don't care in which group it will be found.

Let's change it and try to search only in group A ("SITE (identification, title, address)" as you described it):

```
select * from sites where tsvector @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'sample:A');
```

-- this must return nothing because word `'sample'` sits only in group D ("AUDIT (sample_id)"). Indeed:

```
select * from sites where tsvector @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'sample:D');
```

-- will again return us our record.

Notice, that you need to use `to_tsquery(..)`, not `plainto_tsquery(..)` to be able to address 4 groups. So you need to sanitize your input yourself (avoid using or remove special characters like `&` and `|` because they have special meaning in `tsquery` values).

And the good news is that you can combine different groups in a single query, like this:

```
select * from sites where tsvector @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'sample:D & london:A');
```

The other way to go (e.g. if you have to work with more than 4 groups) is having multiple tsvectors, each one sitting in a separate column, build them using single query, create index (you can create single index on multiple `tsvector` columns) and query addressing separate columns. It's similar to what I explained above, but perhaps less efficient.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much @Nick . Will take a look into your suggestion soon.

Comment: Hey @Nick I forgot to say you big thanks ) I tested you approach and it works brilliant! Thanks you so much friend

Answer (score 1):

Things seem a little simpler in Postgres 10, as the to_tsvector function supports json.  So for example this works nicely:

```
UPDATE dataset SET search_vector = to_tsvector('english',
'{
  "abstract":"Abstract goes here",
  "useConstraints":"None",
  "dataQuality":"Good",
  "Keyword":"historic",
  "topicCategory":"Environment",
  "responsibleOrganisation":"HES"
}'::json)
where dataset_id = 4;
```

Note I haven't tried this on a deeply nested structure, but don't see why it wouldn't work